# Customize UIAlertController in iOS 8 to include standard elements like UITableView

Tags: customization, ios8, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am used to customize `UIAlertViews` through the [`alert setValue:someView forKey:@"accessoryView"]` method. This creates customizable content for UIAlertViews with custom heights. However it only works on iOS7 and down. In iOS8 the `UIAlertController` have taken over, and I cannot customize it anymore, it will cut the height of the `UIAlertView`.

Is it impossible because of misuse of the `UIAlertController`, or how am I supposed to do it?
I am trying to incorporate a UITableView inside a UIAlertController with `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`.

Thx.

Comment: I ended up using this library instead https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview, and abandoned the UIAlertController.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I ran into the same issue right now. I looked at the private header for UIAlertController (https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertController.h) and found a promising property: `contentViewController`

And it turned out to be exactly the same as `accessoryView` used to be for UIAlertView, the difference being that you need to assign a UIViewController to this property rather than a UIView.

```
UIViewController *v = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
v.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[alertController setValue:v forKey:@"contentViewController"];
```

That piece of code will show a red view on the alert view! Happy UIAlertController customizing ;)

PS. It is a private property but using KVC there shouldn't be a problem App Store wise, I think.

**Edit:**

Some people complained that this isn't very safe. It's not a public API, so yes, Apple could change it in any release, causing this method to fail.

To make sure your entire app doesn't crash if that happens you could wrap the KVC call in a `try` block. If the property changes your controller won't show the content view, but it also won't crash:

```
@try {
    [alertController setValue:v forKey:@"contentViewController"];
}
@catch(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Failed setting content view controller: %@", exception);
}
```

Using this method in production can be risky, and I don't recommend it for important alerts.

Comment: How can you adjust the height of the alertcontroller using this method?

Comment: You can override `-preferredContentSize` to return a custom size in the view controller that you are setting as `contentViewController`.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this has been accepted by the app store?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this method and it has been accepted.

Comment: Is it allowed by Apple? or Is it depend on reviewer? I just wanna make sure before I use it.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, because you're assigning it via KVO it can't and won't be detected by Apple's static analyzer and so it will pass the reviewing process.

Comment: Works on iOS 9 too. Amazing!

Comment: Just discovered: `UIAlertAction` also has `contentViewController` property.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic true, interesting!

Comment: We did something similar using KVO to access the `_buttons` on a `UIAlertView` a few years ago. Then they changed the name of the identifier and all our IAPs stopped working on iOS 8. Not a fun few days rushing out fixes for 20 apps. I heavily advise ***against*** this solution

Comment: Question is what do you *strongly* suggest instead?

Comment: I suggest not bothering to shoehorn this functionality into the native alert. Many people have gone and replicated the native alerts, producing near perfect replicas that handle all of the rotation/size/interaction edge cases. I've had success with SDCAlertView @ https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView

Comment: Whether you found a trick to get around the Apple review or not, you just really shouldn't be accessing and relying on private Apple properties. I completely agree with Adam Kaplan on this, and James Webster's experience should be a good warning against this practice as well.

Comment: @Erik Whether it's a good practice to use this in the App Store or not, it answers the question. The question didn't ask for a public API (the example in the question is even a private property). If you want to use this method or not doesn't change the fact that this is exactly what the question asked for.

Comment: It would be irresponsible NOT to point out the drawbacks of that approach. And the onus is not be on the person asking the question to say "and don't suggest anything that will get me In trouble later on" every time..That should be assumed.

Comment: @PeterJohnson in the question he says he is already using the KVC method for UIAlertView. The whole point of the question was to find out how to set custom a view using KVC for UIAlertController. If there was a public API for it, the question wouldn't exist. The whole premise of the question is that there is no public API to set a custom view.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I will probably go grab a customisable controller from Cocoa Controls

Answer (score 12):

I suggest not your wasting time trying to cram additional UI into a place where isn't supposed to be. Based on the last few years of improvements, Apple will probably add a custom view in the next iOS. Until then, have a look at a framework designed to handle this exact situation without subverting any best practices: [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView)

It supports alerts that imitate the native alerts on iOS 7,8,9, including handling all of the nasty edge cases around sizing, button types, rotation, etc. It does support arbitrary custom views within the alert.

[image: SDCAlertView demo gif]

I use this library in Yahoo YMPromptKit for custom push notification prompts that look exactly like iOS native. Here's another example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily customize the UIView adding the controls needed and present it modally, unless  you have any other specific reason to use only  UIAlertController.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=UIAlertview

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just a one of line of code using my UIAlertController category and replace existing alerts in application, check it [here](https://github.com/m1entus/UIAlertController-MZStyle).

[image]

Comment: That would have been great, but unfortunately it doesn't work with action sheets on iPad.