# MvvmCross dialog on android, modal on ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a screen with 1 button. When clicking that button, a list of items should be shown (in which the user can select multiple items).

On android, i would like to do this using a dialog. I create a "DialogService" that does this, no problem.

On iOS, however, it seems that the best practice is to display a fullscreen tableview, for example as a modalView. Is it possible to do this without using a custom viewpresenter (e.g. modalViewPresenter)? I would very much prefer to have identical navigation on both platforms and just have different implementations of "DialogService"

Comment: Which types of items do you want to support? What you are trying to achieve isn't fully clear. In any case, did you consider using a [`Picker`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/)?

Comment: I want to support multiple selection of items - Picker does not support this, and is not well suited for it

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to make one platform look and act like another is generally not a great idea as things start to look weird for the users.

But if you want to do it anyway I would start by trying to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910246/1107580 (it is in objective-c) then trying to bind to the tableview that is in the alertcontroller.