# Create radioButton inside showAlert in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, radio-button

As far as I know, we can give a listener to Alert like "No" and "Exit" in showAlert. 
So if we pressed exit or ok we can do what we want.

```
Are you sure want to exit
Exit            No
```

Is it possible to put radioButton inside showAlert ?
example :

```
o Juice
o Food
o Furniture
Exit   Go
```

Something like this, if i choose Juice and pressed Go, I will direct it to JuiceController. 
Is this can be done? or showAlert only can handle 2 action only ?

Comment: Here's a Stack question about putting a table view in the alert controller. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39253296/5901353
This may get you quite close to what you're looking for. Give it a try and if you need further help, post your question with some code.

Comment: make use of Action sheet or make a custom view like alert

Comment: @iOSGeek any reference please ?

Comment: Should I show you a demo project using action sheet ?

Comment: that would be good, or maybe how to make a custom view inside alert its fine too @iOSGeek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this link . I made a project as per your requirement using actionSheet. you can just make use of this code for reference and embed it in your project

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz8kF1Gedr7fd0JzcTh6c0JVMGs

As if you want to increase the height of action sheet yes you can do it

method 1 - Use this to increase actionSheet height and increase the height of view Embedded in it

```
func showAleert(){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet) //if you increase actionSheet height to move default button down increase \n \n count and get your layout proper


        let margin:CGFloat = 10.0
        let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin, width: alertController.view.bounds.size.width - margin * 4.0, height: 320)
        let customView = UIView(frame: rect)

        customView.backgroundColor = .clear //Background colour as clear

        customView.addSubview(buttonn)
        customView.addSubview(buttonn1)
        customView.addSubview(buttonn2)

        customView.addSubview(label)
        customView.addSubview(label1)
        customView.addSubview(label2)

        alertController.view.addSubview(customView)
        let ExitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

            if self.juiceBool == true {
                //go to juice Controller
                print("juice")
            }
            if self.FoodBool == true{
                //go to food controller
                print("food")
            }
            if self.FurnitureBool == true{
                //go to furniture controller
                print("furniture")
            }
            if (self.juiceBool == false) && (self.FurnitureBool == false) && (self.FoodBool == false){
                //peform your operation like naything you want safety side
                print("Not selected Any")
            }


        })

        let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.80) //here you can define new height for action Sheet
        alertController.view.addConstraint(height);

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})
        alertController.addAction(ExitAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
        }

    }
```

Method 2 - As a View is added you can add scrollView Anything you like IF your option Succeeds more than Like 10,30 or big in number make use of method 1 and give a proper height and then add a scroll view in embedded view with multiple buttons

or

you can just add upto 10 options if you modify actionSheet by using method 1

Comment: Welcome, Happy to Help :)

Comment: by the way I have a few question, if my choice is more than 3 type, and then the button will fill up the alert page, does the page can be scroll up/down ?

Comment: Please check @StevenTan

Comment: that make sense, the first option is better i guess. Probably there will be a lot of choice. Thanks mate that really helpful !

Comment: I think increasing \n\n count will work. So, no need to add that height code [  alertController.view.addConstraint(height); ] I had written