# How can I create tableView in alertView with default values?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

My code is this:

```
let alrController = UIAlertController(title: "Membri", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
alrController.view.addSubview(tableView)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Esci", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in})
alrController.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alrController, animated: true, completion:{})
```

I want to populate (but I don't know how) the `tableView` with this values in my array: `names["name1","name2","name3"]`
Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to add those values as options in alertView?

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896005/ios-8-and-later-uitableview-inside-an-uialertcontroller)

Comment: `UIAlertController` doesn't actually support adding subviews.

Comment: This code is right and shows a tableView in the alert. But I can't populate the tableView with values

Comment: @Marco Please follow the above link, you may get some help to solve this.

Comment: @Marco From the documentation for `UIAlertController`: *"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*. Adding subviews is not supported. You may get it to work but that doesn't mean it is supported. And what works now may break in the next iOS update.

Answer (score 1):

To populate an action sheet, you don't add a tableView.  Instead, you simply add the actions and it will create and manage the tableView privately.

For a recent tutorial, see [UIAlertController Examples](http://irekasoft.com/blog/uialertcontroller-examples)

The idea is that you'd create an UIAlertAction for each String in your array, including a closure for what to do when user taps that action row.

```
for name in names
{
    let namedAction = UIAlertAction(title: name, style: .default) 
    { (action) in
        // do something when this action is chosen (tapped)
    }
    alrController.addAction(namedAction)
}
```

Comment: I only want to show the names, when I click on a button before

Comment: An action sheet is meant to be a simple set of choices to present to the user.  See [Apple's HIG on action sheets](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/).  If you want to do something more complex, I advise you avoid the action sheet and create a new view (and view controller) to be displayed modally in your app.

Comment: Alternatively, consider creating and displaying a second action sheet populated with your names, once the user taps a specific action in the first action sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the following `tableView dataSource` methods in order to populate this data and also set `tableView` `datasource` to `alertController` like below:-

```
tableView.dataSource = alertController
```

> TableView DataSource method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names[section].count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
guard let cell: yourCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as? yourCustomCell 
else {
  fatalError("yourCustomCell not found")
}
cell.textLabel.text = names[indexpath.row]
return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **custom `UIViewController` transition** to achieve this kind of functionality.

This link: https://github.com/pgpt10/Custom-Animator will give you an idea of how you can achieve that.